# what library is able to extract SIFT features in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, computer-vision, python-module

In python which library is able to extract SIFT visual descriptors? I know opencv has an implementation but it is not free to use and skimage does not include SIFT particularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest VLFeat, another open source vision library. It also has a python wrapper. The implementation of SIFT in VLFeat is modified from the original algorithm, but I think the performance is good.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vlfeat-ctypes/0.1.4 is this the wrapper you talked about ?

Comment: I am using this one https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvlfeat/0.1.1a3, use boost.python to build.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV **is free** to use.

But **SIFT itself as algorithm is patented**, so if you would make your own implementation of SIFT, not based on Lowe`s code, you still could not use it in commercial application. So, **unless you have got a license for SIFT, no library with it, is free**.

But you can consult with patent guys - some countries like Russia does not allow to patent algorithms - so you can you SIFT inside such country.

Comment: I am not concerned with the patent issues and question is not that. Thanks anyway.